# MySql conditional SQL. Is my scenario possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, conditional-statements

Let me set up the situation first.

I have a "users" table with X fields, the fields dont really matter for my question except for "visibility". Visibility is a tinyint and the values mean the following (0 = visible to all, 1 = visible to friends only, and 2 = invisible).

I also have a friends table `(id, user_id, target_user_id)`. `user_id` is friends with `target_user_id`. Easy enough so far right?

Here is where it gets sticky. Im writing a PHP API and my class method looks kinda like this:

```
public function getUsers($requester, $page, $num) {}
```

- the `$requester` is the user id of the person requesting the users
- the `$page` is the pagination page number
- the `$num` is the number of items per page

What I want to do in SQL is get `$num` users from the users table if their visibility field is = 0 or 1. If the visibility flag is 1 however, I need to make sure the user id and the $requester are friends in the friends table and only return that user if they are friends.

I thought about using PHP to filter the visibility after I get my results back but the pagination (limit) will be screwed up if I ask for 5 records for example and one or more user has visibility set to 1 and are not friends with the requester. This pretty much has to be done entirely thru sql.

Possible??

Comment: did you try anything? it is pretty easy... Actually you made that condition by yourself in your question, you just have to rewrite it to sql

Comment: Possible, yes, have a play and see what you come up with.  A good place to consider looking at the `WHERE` syntax, as all you are asking for is `WHERE visibility = 0 OR (visibility = 1 AND somethingToCheckFriends)`.  A `LEFT JOIN` will most likely feature somewhere too.  Read up on them, do some research, and try some things out.

Comment: For them to be friends does there need to be a record from A to B AND from B to A in the friends table?

Comment: A to B is good enough. Technically in my code its more of a Twitter follow relationship but I used friends here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a temp table 'temp' with same structure as users.

```
select * into temp From users where visibility=0 or visibility=1;
Select * from temp, friends where (temp.visibility=0) or (temp.user_id = friends.target_user_id);
```

Don't forget to empty the temp table.

I haven't tried the second query yest, let me know what output you got.

```
select * from users, friends where (users.visibility=0) or (users.visibility=1 and users.user_id = friends.target_user_id);
```

Comment: That got it. I forgot that I could select from two different tables. Here is the final solution:

`SELECT users. *
FROM users, friends
WHERE (
users.visibility =0
)
OR (
users.visibility =1
AND (
users.id = friends.user_id
AND follows.target_user_id =<requester id>
)
)
GROUP BY users.id`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use LEFT JOIN for this.. something like

```
"SELECT * 
FROM users t1 
LEFT JOIN friends t2 ON t2.user_id=t1.id AND t1.visibility=1
INNER JOIN user t3 ON t3.id=t2.target_user_id
WHERE t1.visibility=0 OR t1.visibility=1
LIMIT ".($page*$num).",".$num
```

Comment: This looks close but if visibility is 0, there doesn't need to be any joins at all. That's why I asked about conditional statements like IF or CASE. Every user will have a different visibility flag and those with a 1 need to be checked for the relationship in the friends table. If that relationship doesnt exist, then that user record shouldn't be returned.

Comment: This is not correct SQL but it's almost like it needs to be something like this:

   SELECT * FROM users
   WHERE (visibility=0 OR visibility = 1) AND
   (IF (visibility = 1) SELECT * from friends where user_id=users.id AND target_user_id=$requester, TRUE, FALSE)

The incorrect IF statement above is meant to read if the visibility is 1, execute the sql statement and return true if a match was found or false otherwise.

Comment: added condition to left join.. maybe that will help?